# Is it possible to use Register-PSRepository with private gitlab server (internal/private project)

Tags: powershell, gitlab, nuget

I have an issue with adding repository in powershell with

```
Register-PSRepository -name gitlab -PublishLocation https://gitlab.private.com/api/v4/projects/3280491/packages/nuget/index.json -SourceLocation https://gitlab.private.com/api/v4/projects/3280491/packages/nuget/index.json -InstallationPolicy Trusted -Credential (Get-Credential) -PackageManagementProvider NuGet
```

credential user:  my gitlab username, password: my generated access token with api privilege.

If then i will want to query modules inside:
find-module -Repository gitlab
WARNING: Query Url https://gitlab.private.com/api/v4/projects/2797/packages/nuget/index.json is invalid.
it throws me this error.

I have tried the same with my account on gitlab.com with a free account. And i have the same issue.
There is no issue if i will create a project that is available to everyone. This happens if project is internal/private.

If i will use nuget , then i have no issue with publishing my module to gitlab / private gitlab, i have no issue with doing nuget install ... .
Any idea why this would not work with powershell cmdlets ?
I am not sure if i understood some messages i found on internet about issues with powershellget, as if it would have issues with storing credentials.
Maybe someone seen this issue, and understands it more and could explain ?

I can find the module inside the repository:
Find-Module -Repository gitlab  -Credential $mycred

```
Version              Name                                Repository
-------              ----                                ----------
0.4.2                PrivateAutomation                 gitlab
```

But when piped to Install-module it does not work
DEBUG: 00:00:01.7085410 Completed downloading 'https://gitlab.private.net/api/v4/projects/97/packages/nuget/metadata/privateautomation/0.4.2.json'.
WARNING: An internal error occurred: The JSON object returned by the NuGet API does not match expected schema. Expected property: 'type'. Check the debug stream for the full JSON object dump.

I am running powershell v7.1 / powershellget 2.2.5
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GitLab uses nuget v3](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/nuget_repository/) endpoint for the repository. v3 is not supported in the current stable version of PowerShellGet, but it is in [PowerShellGet 3.0](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellGet/3.0.16-beta16) which is in preview at the time of writing.